# Mavericks won't install on brand new SSD drive

Tags: macos, hard-drive, usb, ssd

Mid 2010 MacBook Pro 6,2
Had 10.9.1 installed on an SSD drive which failed.
Got a replacement drive (same brand, model)
Have a USB bootable thumb drive with 10.9.0 installation files on it
Mac boots from USB and install starts
It sees the new drive (formatted Mac OS Extended Journaled)
I set the date via Terminal so that isn't the issue
Goes through the preparing to install routine, and then eventually fails with the following error:

> An error occurred while preparing the installation.  Try running this
>   application again.

Saw previous posts which said date was incorrect; but date has been set correctly.
I've confirmed the files exist on the USB drive.
After it fails and I go to Disk Utility, the SSD drive is suddenly not visible.
Anyone have a clue?

Comment: Is there a Trim enabler with that disk. what brand/model is it?

Comment: No.  It's an OWC Mercury Electra 3G

Comment: What does the Installer log say?  You can enable it from the menu.  During installation, the menu is invisible, but can be shown by hovering over with the mouse.  Alternatively or in case the installer took a hit and got corrupt, you could install the original system (Mac OS X 10.6), update it and then download Mac OS X 10.9 again from the App Store.  It's more tedious, but possible, if you obtained Mavericks when it was still available.

Comment: I'll check the installer log.  However 10.6.3 won't recognize the SSD drive.  Cause I already have that install cd.  Let me check the installer log.

Comment: Point taken.  Though you could install 10.6 also onto an external HDD and download Mavericks there.  Unless even 10.6.8 does not detect the SSD, this would also be possible if you have a Mac-formatted external HDD with 10+ GB space.  Other than that, if you have another Mac, you can try to create another boot media there.

Comment: I am not a person who understands log files.  However the following text did appear amongst the verbose language in the installer log file.

Comment: "Could not write to /var/log/CDIS.custom.  Cannot connect to /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.socket: no such file or directory. Failed to unlock login keychain.

Comment: While I'm no developer either, it seems to me that your installer misses something or got some files changed.  If you have access to another Mac system, for simplicity sake I would see about downloading the installer and creating the install media again.  If you have a different USB thumb drive, I would also give it a try to use that other drive if the current one fails again.

Comment: From my time working at an AASP, we ran in to this problem a couple of times. It always seemed to be that the bootable installer we had created had "expired" somehow and we had to recreate a new one. If you recall when you created the boot drive, try setting the system time to a day or so after that. Any reason you don't want to run Yosemite or use Internet Recovery? Otherwise, as @Phoenix says, create a new installer from another Mac if you can.

Comment: It looks like you are not getting anywhere with this. Try the Apple way.

Comment: never used Internet Recovery and tried this morning.  Unfortunately the install won't proceed because my apple id has not been used in the app store.  This is a business account and I can't enter a credit card to the apple id.  I'll try creating an installer from another Mac.

Comment: to answer your question about why I had not tried to install Yosemite, this is a 4 year old machine and I figured Yosemite might be overkill.  Plus since I had a 10.9 install USB key . . . why not use that.  I'll create another installer USB key.

Comment: I just installed on OWC Aura X SSD on a MacBook Retina, and the instructions cautioned that the computer had to be updated to High Sierra *before* the install, as the High Sierra installer had a firmware update required by the computer to run the SSD. I did so, and the installation went easily. It may be that your new SSD also requires such a firmware upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem "an error occurred while preparing the installation. Try running this applications again". When you run the installer again, instead of trying to install to the SSD, install the Mavericks OS onto the usb drive (hopefully you have a big enough usb drive to contain mac os and installer) and then reboot with the USB Mavericks OS. Computer is now running os off usb drive. Then open the installer that is also on usb and find the ssd. I had to restart once to get the ssd to show up in disk utility, but you might get lucky. Good luck hope it works for you. (my ssd OWC Mercury 240).